# Site Search for Website

Tags: search

I have a website developed in php and Joomla.Now i want to add a site search facility that searches on the contents of the particular site.I have no idea what to do?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code this up using some SQL queries and PHP codes to retrieve the contents of your Joomla posts...

or you can use Google's custom search http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate Google Search. http://www.google.com/sitesearch/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Joomla Site Search Extensions: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search you could integrate.